# How monitoring application with C# betwen SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2019

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, desktop-application

I have two SQL Server servers. Server A - SQL Server - 2005 and server B - SQL Server 2019 faster. Both of them  are the same but with different versions.

How to monitor procedures and functions between two servers, one 2005 and the other 2019 using C#. The two are the same but with different versions.

I want to develop a desktop application that monitors the updates that are made on the 2005 server and updates 2019.
I want only a tip. No C# Code. Thanks.

Is this possible?
I need a little bit idea to start my  code.

Comment: Are you trying to compare the schemas or do something similar to SQL Profiler where you are literally monitoring incoming queries and statements?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you mean to monitor performance metrics (CPU, memory, storage etc) or monitor changes to the data, or monitor changes to the structure (the table and procedure definitions etc). Regardless, the answer is going to be similar for all of them: either write code to do it, or find a tool that does it for you. The first is too broad of a question for this site (we're not here to write your code for you) and finding a tool isn't on topic for this site (you'll need to do your own shopping)

Comment: It works like this.
Migration has already been done  to server 2019.
but there are programmers who update procedures and functions constantly. What I want is through a C# application, I can monitor the updates of procs and functions in A and apply B.
I believe that for this I have to keep comparing the two servers , I think .I dont  wish a code . Only a tip

Comment: The Visual Studio data tools has a database compare option.

Comment: Have you considered changing the process? Developers probably shouldn't just be applying changes directly to a database. Instead, they can write scripts to update the database (these are usually called "migrations") and then you can have a tool monitor which migrations have been applied and automatically apply the next set as part of a deployment process. You can read about processes like that [here](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/05/03/stack-overflow-how-we-do-deployment-2016-edition/#database-migrations). And of course there are tools such as [DbUp](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, there are many monitoring tools out there that have more functionality and sophistication than you could possibly achieve as an individual. Check out offerings from *Redgate* Lighthouse sounds like it might do what you need and I think it's free.

Comment: Both Servers are DEV

Answer (score 1):

to monitor db activities you can use sql server features like sql job , db management (email feature) to get update via email about event occured to servers .

to view both server's activities from one server you create a link server from sql19 to sql05 .